# How to maintain the log source host using logstash

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog, graylog

I am following the steps in this blog to set up rsyslog + logstash + graylog2 and I can't figure out how to replace the @source_host attribute in logstash using the mutate -> replace filter.

In the exmaple the author replaces his @source_host with a string value but I'd like to use the actual value that is parsed from in this case a syslog.

```
mutate {
  type => loc1
  replace => ["@source_host", "loc1"]
}
mutate {
  type => loc2
 replace => ["@source_host", "loc2"]
}
```

How do I actually maintain the original source host in my logs?

Comment: Can you add the link to the blog?

Answer (score 1):

if the field has already been matched to the record, and is available then you might be able to do this;

```
mutate {
    type => loc2
    replace => [ "@source_host","%{this_field}" ]
}
```

(though I have not tried replacing out the @source_host field before, but give it a try and let us know how it went... ;-)

[the blog?](http://petes-brain.com/2011/12/my-logging-setup-rsyslog-logstash-and-graylog2/)

Comment: I had already tried your suggestion when I originally attempted to use logstash between rsyslog and graylog and had no luck.  I've since moved to just sending logs directly to graylog2 from rsyslog and it's working fine.  I might revisit this again some day if I need to do more granular filtering and formatting of my logs with logstash.